# I don't understand one of the steps in solving Green's function for diffusion

Tags: integration

Why is it that 
$\int_0 ^\infty u^4e^{-u^2}du = $
$  \left[\frac {d^2}{d\alpha^2}\int_0 ^\infty e^{-\alpha u^2}du \right]_{\alpha = 1} $?

Comment: Do the leibniz rule without worrying about wether you may or may not to get from RHS to LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha u^{2}}du$. We are interested in $I''(1)$.

Now differentiate with respect to $\alpha$. Then by [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) and [Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have

$I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha u^{2}}du \Rightarrow I'(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (-u^{2}\ e^{-\alpha\  u^{2}} du) \Rightarrow I''(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (u^{4}\ e^{-\alpha\  u^{2}} du)\\ \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} (u^{4}\ e^{-\alpha\  u^{2}} du) = \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}\alpha^{2}} e^{-\alpha\  u^{2}} du\right] \Rightarrow I''(1) = \left[\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}\alpha^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha\  u^{2}} du \right]_{a=1} $.

The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Use differentiation under the integral sign.

$$\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2}\right|_1e^{-\alpha u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\int\limits_{[0,+\infty)}(u^2)^2e^{-1\cdot u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$